# Mongoose - Read and update based on read data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the Model that I'm using:

```
const TestSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    array: [{ type: Number, required: true }],
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt' }});
```

**I need** an endpoint where this document is read, and then add a new element into the "array" property; this new element will be the length of the array. So, if I send three requests to the endpoint, the array object should have ["0", "1", "2"].

To achieve this, **I am trying to use** transactions like this:

```
 const session = await startSession();

            await session.withTransaction(async () => {
                const doc = await Test.findOne({id: "0"});
                if(!doc) { res.status(400).send("Bad request");  return;}

                doc.array.push()
                doc.array.push(doc.array.length);
                
                await doc.save();
    
                res.send(doc);
            });
           
            session.endSession();
```

To test the endpoint, I am using JMeter, sending 10 simultaneous requests and this is result:

```
"array": [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,6,10,12,13]
```

[MongoDB Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxPBu.png)

What is the correct way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** This is a simplification of a real problem. In the real problem, I read a document, based on its content I do some operations (check, maybe throw an error...) and then I do the save. In this case, I think using findOneAndUpdate very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using the variable "session" in the reads and writes.
Solution:

```
const session = await startSession();

            await session.withTransaction(async () => {
                const doc = await Test.findOne({id: "0"}).session(session);;
                if(!doc) { res.status(400).send("Bad request");  return;}

                doc.array.push()
                doc.array.push(doc.array.length);
                
                doc.update()
                await doc.save({session});
    
                res.send(doc);
            });
```